# Toggle adapter for TitledPane

Tags: javafx

In my application, I want to apply the behavior of a `ToggleGroup` to a group of `TitledPane`s. To do so, I implemented this:

*ToggleAdapter.java*

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;

public class ToggleAdapter implements Toggle {
    final private TitledPane titledPane;
    final private ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup> toggleGroupProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private ToggleAdapter(TitledPane titledPane) {
        this.titledPane = titledPane;
    }

    @Override
    public ToggleGroup getToggleGroup() {
        return toggleGroupProperty.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void setToggleGroup(ToggleGroup toggleGroup) {
        toggleGroupProperty.set(toggleGroup);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup> toggleGroupProperty() {
        return toggleGroupProperty;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected() {
        return titledPane.isExpanded();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        titledPane.setExpanded(selected);
    }

    @Override
    public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
        return titledPane.expandedProperty();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getUserData() {
        return titledPane.getUserData();
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserData(Object value) {
        titledPane.setUserData(value);
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableMap<Object, Object> getProperties() {
        return FXCollections.emptyObservableMap();
    }

    public static Toggle asToggle(final TitledPane titledPane) {
        return new ToggleAdapter(titledPane);
    }
}
```

*sample.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox spacing="7.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <TitledPane fx:id="titledPane1" text="Title 1">
         <content>
            <TextArea minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="125.0" prefRowCount="1" wrapText="true" />
         </content>
      </TitledPane>
      <TextField />
      <TitledPane fx:id="titledPane2" expanded="false" text="Title 2">
         <content>
            <TextArea minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="125.0" prefRowCount="1" wrapText="true" />
         </content>
      </TitledPane>
      <TitledPane fx:id="titledPane3" expanded="false" text="Title 3">
         <content>
            <TextArea minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="125.0" prefRowCount="1" wrapText="true" />
         </content>
      </TitledPane>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="14.0" left="14.0" right="14.0" top="14.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

*Controller.java*

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;

public class Controller {
    @FXML private TitledPane titledPane1;
    @FXML private TitledPane titledPane2;
    @FXML private TitledPane titledPane3;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        final var toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

        final var toggle1 = ToggleAdapter.asToggle(titledPane1);
        toggle1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

        final var toggle2 = ToggleAdapter.asToggle(titledPane2);
        toggle2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

        final var toggle3 = ToggleAdapter.asToggle(titledPane3);
        toggle3.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

        toggleGroup.selectToggle(toggle1);

    }
}
```

*Main.java*

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

My naive approach doesn't work, but I have no idea why not. Any ideas?

EDIT: I am aware of `Acordion`, but this would not be suitable because I cannot place all three `TitledPane`s in the same parent container.

Comment: Here is the implementation for `ToggleButton`. Maybe you can get some ideas from it. https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.java

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. The is already implemented in the standard API by the [`Accordion`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Accordion.html) control.

Comment: Hi @kleopatra I just modified the example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing the implementation of `ToggleAdapter` to this actually solves the problem:

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;

import java.util.Optional;

public class ToggleAdapter implements Toggle {
    final private TitledPane titledPane;
    final private ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup> toggleGroupProperty = new ObjectPropertyBase<>() {
        private ToggleGroup old;

        @Override
        protected void invalidated() {
            if (old != null) {
                old.getToggles().remove(ToggleAdapter.this);
            }
            old = get();
            if (get() != null && get().getToggles().contains(ToggleAdapter.this) == false) {
                get().getToggles().add(ToggleAdapter.this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object getBean() {
            return ToggleAdapter.this;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "toggleGroup";
        }
    };

    @Override
    public ToggleGroup getToggleGroup() {
        return toggleGroupProperty.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void setToggleGroup(ToggleGroup toggleGroup) {
        toggleGroupProperty.set(toggleGroup);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup> toggleGroupProperty() {
        return toggleGroupProperty;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected() {
        return titledPane.isExpanded();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        titledPane.setExpanded(selected);
    }

    @Override
    public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
        return titledPane.expandedProperty();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getUserData() {
        return titledPane.getUserData();
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserData(Object value) {
        titledPane.setUserData(value);
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableMap<Object, Object> getProperties() {
        return FXCollections.emptyObservableMap();
    }

    public static Toggle asToggle(final TitledPane titledPane) {
        return new ToggleAdapter(titledPane);
    }

    public ToggleAdapter(TitledPane titledPane) {
        this.titledPane = titledPane;

        selectedProperty().addListener(obs -> {
            Optional.ofNullable(getToggleGroup()).ifPresent(toggleGroup -> {
                if (isSelected()) {
                    toggleGroup.selectToggle(this);
                } else if (toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle() == this) {
                    toggleGroup.selectToggle(null);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you, +James_D for the idea on how to change the implementation.

Comment: wrong in not implementing the broken invariant I mentioned in James' answer

Comment: @kleopatra Are you referring to this? https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/71a7d43c7739800fc330885260bf843ac3bc114f/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.java#L213 I am not quite sure which case it handles, tbh.

Comment: copied comment: as bad as the toggleGroup is, I think any solution should maintain the invariant `assertTrue(tg.getToggles().contains(toggle))` for all managed toggles - which can be handled in the adapter's toggleGroup property (look at ToggleButton, as @Sedrick already noted :)

Comment: I do not understand when this invariant could occur and in which case it must be handled. Especially since I can't see how the toggleGroup property relates to it.

Comment: Always. Look at ToggleButton.

Comment: I added now what I believe you are referring to, tho I took the implementation from `RadioMenuItem`. I have to stay, that I am still not sure why this is needed, and I don't understand the `old = get();', since `old` is never used after that.

Comment: _old is never used after that_ think again or just look at the first line in invalidated :)

Comment: to improve: a) use the cached value always b) replace contains == false with !contains

Comment: First of all, I am not sure what you mean by always use the cached value; as far as I know, I do exactly as it is done in the RadioMenuItem. b) is not an improvement, that's just a question about the established coding style in a certain project.

But most important: I am certainly grateful that you took the time to help me, but I am not here to be educated. Please either answer my question or don't, but I am not your student and you are not my teacher.

Comment: it's not about you or me - it's about future readers: so answers should be as good as possible ... crappy original (in core javafx) is no excuse to replicate its crappyness *off

Answer (score 3):

First, you're reinventing the wheel. Don't do that; there's already a control, [`Accordion`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Accordion.html), that implements exactly what you're trying to do here.

All you need is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Accordion?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>

<Accordion expandedPane="${titledPane1}" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <panes>
      <TitledPane fx:id="titledPane1" text="Title 1" expanded="true">
         <content>
            <TextArea minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="125.0" prefRowCount="1" wrapText="true" />
         </content>
      </TitledPane>
      <TitledPane fx:id="titledPane2" expanded="false" text="Title 2">
         <content>
            <TextArea minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="125.0" prefRowCount="1" wrapText="true" />
         </content>
      </TitledPane>
      <TitledPane fx:id="titledPane3" expanded="false" text="Title 3">
         <content>
            <TextArea minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="125.0" prefRowCount="1" wrapText="true" />
         </content>
      </TitledPane>
   </panes>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="14.0" left="14.0" right="14.0" top="14.0" />
   </padding>
</Accordion>
```

and

```
public class Controller {
    
    @FXML private Accordion accordion ;
    @FXML private TitledPane titledPane1;
    @FXML private TitledPane titledPane2;
    @FXML private TitledPane titledPane3;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        accordion.setExpandedPane(titledPane1);
    }
}
```

The `ToggleAdapter` is not required.

The reason your code doesn't work is that you're assuming, I think, that the `ToggleGroup` observes the `selected` state of each of its toggles and updates the other toggle's state when one is selected. This isn't the case; it's actually the responsibility of the toggle implementation to maintain single selection in its toggle group, if it so desires. You could do this by adding a listener to the selected state in the `ToggleAdapter` (but again, to emphasize, it's always wrong to reinvent functionality defined in the standard API).

```
private ToggleAdapter(TitledPane titledPane) {
    this.titledPane = titledPane;
    selectedProperty().addListener(obs -> {
        ToggleGroup tg = getToggleGroup();
        if (tg != null) {
            if (isSelected()) {
                tg.selectToggle(this);
            } else if (tg.getSelectedToggle() == this) {
                tg.selectToggle(null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question: I do want to apply the behavior of a `ToggleGroup` to a list of `TitledPane`. `Accordion` is a `Control` and only works if all `TitlePane`s in question are children of the accordion.

Comment: @Hannes It’s still not clear why an `Accordion` (or at worst multiple `Accordion`s) wouldn’t provide the functionality you’re looking for. But if you do have some other use case, doesn’t the modification to `ToggleAdapter` solve the issue?

Comment: just a side comment: _it's actually the responsibility of the toggle implementation to maintain single selection_ that's true and is what's implemented, but to me feels weird (as in completely upside-down ;) for a class that should manage the single selection inside the group.

Comment: @Hannes at the very least, you have to make the toggleGroup aware of your toggle (by adding/removing to/from its list of toggles) - but as James correctly noted, that's not enough because the toggle's selected is expected to manage the group (really really weird if you ask me). Still don't quite understand the why Accordion is not an option? You might wrap all other content into a TitledPane - but don't want to. You want a layout with f.i. TitledPane, SomeControl, TitledPane - such that the middle is always visible but at most one of the titledPanes expanded?

Comment: @kleopatra Agreed, it's weird. I'm sure it made sense to the API designers at the time, but I can't even guess as to what the thinking may have been.

Comment: I believe the `Accordion` does not solve my problem because the `TitledPane`s in my real-world use case is situated in different `Parent`s which are situated in different locations of the UI. Therefore I cannot put all `TitledPane`s into one single parent as it is required for an Accordion to work correctly. In my MRE I tried to remove the complexity of the UI and narrow it down to the pure, technical requirement.

Comment: @Hannes OK, fair enough (though a couple of `VBox`s in an `HBox` would not have been much more complex and would have demonstrated the issue). But the last part of the answer solves your problem, doesn't it?

Comment: @James_D I believe it does, I will put it to a test tonight and will modify my example. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: the edited part indeed does solve the problem - but isn't quite enough: as bad as the toggleGroup is, I think any solution should maintain the invariant `assertTrue(tg.getToggles().contains(toggle))` for all managed toggles - which can be handled in the adapter's toggleGroup property (look at ToggleButton, as @Sedrick already noted :)

Comment: @kleopatra That's true. I'll modify when I get a chance...